# Is the worst-case of this algorithm equal to $\Theta(n)$ or $\Theta(n\lg n)$?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I am trying to find the worst-case complexity of the following algorithm. The input to the algorithm is a list of positive integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and a bound $C$.

- $S\gets$ empty set
- $k\gets0$
- for $i\gets1$ to $n$ do

  - add $i$ to $S$
  - $k\gets k+a_i$
  - if $k>C$

    - $j\gets\arg\max_{i\in S}a_i$
    - $k\gets k - a_j$
    - remove $j$ from $S$

In the worst-case, at each iteration $i$, we go to the if condition and calculate the max. So, if the max operation requires $\Theta(n)$, then the worst-case complexity is $\Theta(n^2)$. As suggested in the comments, $\Theta(n)$ is not the best possible.

Here, I use an array to represent $S$. I can use a heap instead as a data structure to find the max in $\Theta(\lg n)$. So, the worst-case complexity is $\Theta(n\lg n)$. Am I right?

**EDIT:** I found this article https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18119/finding-smallest-k-elements-in-array-in-ok which finds the $k$ smallest elements in $O(k)$ time. My algorithm computes the $|S|$ smallest elements. Hence, it can be done in $O(|S|)$ time. **But** the $|S|$ is not given apriori. This is another issue now. Any help?

Comment: Have you noticed that computing the max in each iteration is re-doing a lot of work over and over again? Can you think of any faster way to update the max, without having to redo all that work?   Perhaps some appropriate data structure might be helpful here.  What data structures have you considered, for storing $S$?

Comment: Do you mean "set"? A set by definition doesn't contain duplicates, so if for example n = 1000, C = 100 and a1..a1000 = 1, the result would be one element { 1 }. Maybe you mean an unordered list?

Comment: Theta (n log n) is easy if you know what data structures to use. Theta (n) - I wouldn't say it's impossible. The result is the m smallest items for some unknown m. Slightly more difficult than finding a percentile which can be done in linear time (because you don't know which percentile you want when you start).

Comment: $S$ is a set. If $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_{1000}=1$, and $C=100$, I would add $1$ to $S$, then $2$ to $S$, etc. So, I would get $S=\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$. I only add to $S$ distinct elements. You are right about sorting but what if I use a list that stores the max values encountered so far. Whenever I update $S$, I update this list. So in every iteration of the for loop, I can calculate the maximum in $O(1)$ time. Like this, I can achieve $\Theta(n)$, Is this right?

Comment: @D.W. I considered a set for $S$, is it enough to calculate the max in $O(1)$?

Comment: A set is a mathematical construct, not a data structure.  What data structures do you know that you could use to store a set?  gnasher mentioned an unordered list; that's one.  Do you know any others?  Try to find as many data structures as you can, and see which ones you could use here to make this fast.

Comment: @kik If you just keep track of the max value, that changes practically every time another item is processed. A heap can always return the largest element in O(log n).

Comment: I don't get it. You mean the max can be done in $O(1)$?

Comment: @kik Nobody said that O(n) is impossible. I said it's difficult. There's a very similar problem that can be solved in O (n), so maybe this one can be done in O (n), maybe not. And actually, the algorithm is definitely not Θ (n log n), because the time is linear if the sum is < C.

Comment: @kik Keeping track of the max won't work in O (1), because every time you take the max, it's removed and it's not the max anymore.

Comment: Yes, true. But, in the worst-case, we may assume that the sum $> C$. In this case, I am not sure of the worst-case complexity.

Comment: Ok. I get now what you said about keeping track of the max. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

You need a data structure that supports the following three operations efficiently:

- insert an element into the set
- delete an element from the set
- find the largest element in the set

There are multiple such data structures.  One reasonable choice is a balanced binary search tree, where all three operations can be implemented in $O(\log n)$ time.